# async functions not executed in server when testing with chai-http

Tags: javascript, express, mocha.js, chai, chai-http

I have the following function in my app.js

```
let memoryCache = require('./lib/memoryCache');
memoryCache.init().then(() => {
   console.log("Configuration loaded on app start", JSON.stringify(memoryCache.getCache()));
});

app.use('/v1', v1);
...
module.exports = app;
```

`memorycache.init` is an async function where data is populated from a database

```
module.exports = function () {
let cache = {};
return {
    init: async () => {
        console.log('called this')
        cache['repairStatus'] = formatData(await getRepairStatus());
        cache['actionStatus'] = formatData(await getActionStatus());
        cache['problemFound'] = formatData(await getProblemFound());
        cache['complaintCode'] = formatData(await getComplaintCode());
        cache['productType'] = formatData(await getProductType());
        console.log('cache is', cache)
    },
    getCache: (key) => {
        if (key) return cache[key] || null;
        else return cache;
    }
}
```

when I try to do a chai-http test, `memorycache.init` is executed after the test is run resulting in an error

```
let res = await chai.request(server).post(url).send(testObject)
```

Output is a 400 error after which the memoryCache is initialized.

How to I correct this?

Entire test:

```
const chai = require('chai');
const getTestJob = require('../../lib/testutils').getTestJob;
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
const server = require('../../../app.js');

chai.use(chaiHttp);
const expect = chai.expect;
const assert = chai.assert;
```

describe(('Api- CreateJob'), () => {
     let url = '/v1/job'
     let testSRJob = getTestJob()

```
 before(async () => {

 })

 beforeEach(() => {

 })

 after(async () => {
 })

 describe('*** HAPPY CASES ***', () => {
   it('successful test', async () => {
   console.log('calling test')
   let result = await chai.request(server).post(url).set('Authorization', 'auth').send(testSRJob)
   if (result.status !== 200) {
     console.log('Status: ', result.status)
     console.log('Error: ', result.error)
     assert.fail()
   } else {
     console.log('Yippie!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')
   }
  });
})
})
```

Output:

```
called this

... some logging from the api tested
Error:  { Error: cannot POST /v1/job (400)
status: 400,
text: '{"message":"Create job failed","code":"E1002","errData":{}}',
method: 'POST',
path: '/v1/job'

>> then failure report in the test

cache is <cache data>
Configuration loaded on app start <cache data>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the code you've listed inside a Mocha life-cycle hook such as `before()` or `beforeEach()`, or inside one an individual test? If it's at global scope, Node might be attempting to execute the Mocha tests parallel to `memoryCache.init()`, which will cause your app to fail due to not being properly initialised.

Comment: it is inside mocha lifecycle. I tried to keep it in the before and also individual test. Both resulted in the same error

Comment: Can you update the code in your question to show the full test?
Also, try returning the `memoryCache.init` promise from the test function itself, to see if that works as intended.